# How to get CSS position: fixed for a background image to work properly?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, frontend

I'm trying to change my image position:fixed however it changes where the image is and I can't even see it anymore now...  I've looked at several posts on here and can't find a solid solution.  Is there a way to get a fixed image which resizes on different window sizes and how do I position this fixed image?

Here is my code:

react jsx:

```
...
<div className="home-root3" style={{backgroundImage: logo2}}>
                <div className="bottom-left">word1</div>
                <div className="bottom-right">word2</div>
                <div className="top-center">word3</div>
            </div>  
...
```

CSS:

```
.home-root3 {        
    position: fixed;
    background:no-repeat;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;    
    /*background-position: 50% 50%;*/
    /*background-size: contain;*/
}
```

Comment: can you build a working reproduction showing your problem?

Comment: Using position: fixed on an element takes it out of the flow of the page, so it's probably hidden behind something else but we'll need to see the rest of your HTML

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.
notice how when you resize the image it scales it to best fit the available space without distorting the image. the key thing here is the background-size and the background-position. try adding more elements and removing the background-attachment to get slightly different behavior

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQqXQV

```css
.home-root3 {
  background: url(https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*OvqueeLCylgdld5YvYZO0A.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.home-root3 div {
  margin: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-root3">
  <div className="bottom-left">word1</div>
  <div className="bottom-right">word2</div>
  <div className="top-center">word3</div>
  <div className="top-center">word4</div>
  <div className="top-center">word5</div>
  <div className="top-center">word6</div>
  <div className="top-center">word7</div>
  <div className="top-center">word8</div>
</div>
```